# Using a function to build a Navigation from Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to build a function which enables me to build a simple Navigation (or list, matter of fact) from a database table.

Problem is, the variables in the brackets don't work, how can I fix this?

```
function buildNav($DbRow, $DbName) {
  $nav_qry = "SELECT $DbRow FROM $DbName WHERE 1";
  $nav_res = mysqli_query($con, $nav_qry);
    echo "<ul>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_res)) {
    echo "<li id='" . $row[$DbRow] . "'><a href='?id=" . $row[$DbRow] . "' class='nav-point'>". $row[$DbRow] ."</a></li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make a new conenction to db. Just add the global variable thus:

```
function buildNav($DbRow, $DbName) {
    global $con;
    //...your sql code goes here
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Yeah, I just realized :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already checked if $nav_res has rows already. So, I suggest you to try the below code to see if it makes any difference.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_res)) { ?>
    <li id='<?php echo $row[$DbRow] ?>'><a href='?id=<?php echo $row[$DbRow] ?>' class='nav-point'><?php echo $row[$DbRow] ?></a></li>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thats not working :-/

        <nav>
          <ul></ul>        
        </nav>

Comment: can you print_r the $nav_res please and also print_r the $row in the while.

Comment: the print_r for $nav_res is 1, I'm not getting any for $row, in fact none of the echo commands I use inside the while-loop is printed, so its not iterating. But if I enter the query in phpmyadmin, I get results

Answer (score 0):

Allright the problem is, the function cannot access the $con variable defined earlier in the document, so If its in the function, the whole thing works.

```
function buildNav($DbRow, $DbName) {
  $con = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
  $nav_qry = "SELECT $DbRow FROM $DbName WHERE 1";
  $nav_res = mysqli_query($con, $nav_qry);
    echo "<ul>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nav_res)) {
    echo "<li id='" . $row['title'] . "'><a href='?id=" . $row['title'] . "' class='nav-point'>". $row['title'] ."</a></li>";
      }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```